# Enigma Force (Uni-Power) vs. Power Cosmic

Tags: marvel, captain-universe

I am confused about the Enigma Force and the Power Cosmic: which one would be more powerful?  I've seen Spider-Man and Hulk as Captain Universe, I also have seen Iron Man as a Herald of Galactus, wielding the Power Cosmic.  Which of these two powers would be stronger?  Has someone ever held them both?

Answer (score 3):

**Has someone ever held them both?**

Yes, the Silver Surfer briefly possessed both the Power Cosmic and the Uni-Power in *[Captain Universe: Silver Surfer #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Universe:_Silver_Surfer_Vol_1_1)*.

> [image]
>
> *Captain Universe: Silver Surfer #1* (January, 2006)

**Which of these two powers would be stronger?**

It's not entirely clear, but in *[Web of Spider-Man Vol. 1 #61](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_61)*, Dr. Doom claimed that a portion of the Uni-Power would've elevated him to a "state of power" greater than the one he was at when he stole the Silver Surfer's Power Cosmic years earlier, in *[Fantastic Four Vol. 1 #57](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_57)* (December, 1966).

> Project Power (Progress Report Crypto-Coded by Victor Von Doom): "I'm ready. In less than one minute I will receive an unknown dosage of unexplained energy. **The result will be transcendence to a state of power greater than that which I once stole from the Silver Surfer.**"
>
> [image]
>
> *Web of Spider-Man Vol. 1 #61* (February, 1990)

Doom didn't know it was a portion of the Uni-Power at the time, which is why he referred to it as "unexplained energy", but it was a sample of power absorbed from ['Cosmic Spider-Man'](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Cosmic_Spider-Man) in *[Spectacular Spider-Man Vol. 1 #160](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_160)*.

> Project Power (Progress Report): Events have outpaced expectations. Retrieving the artifact this time is simplicity itself. A homing device in the modified skull-casing leads me at once to my target. Telemetry read-outs confirm my calculations. **The artifact has absorbed a quantity of the energies Spider-Man expended during the climactic stage of the battle.** Insufficient to allow T.E.S.S.-One the option to re-construct itself, perhaps -- but more than adequate for my needs, I think.
>
> Project Power (Report, continued): "With the power stored in the artifact's skull-casing, I will soon achieve my destiny.  "For power is destiny... and destiny is Doom."
>
> [image]
>
> *Spectacular Spider-Man Vol. 1 #160* (January, 1990)

Comment: Weird then how in that same  Captain Universe: Silver Surfer #1. Silver Surfer beats Captain Universe with apparent ease.

Comment: He beat a rookie Captain Universe, who had the Uni-Power for less than a day, by overloading his body with the addition of the Power Cosmic. It doesn't necessarily follow that the Power Cosmic was supposed to be more powerful than the Uni-Power there. Also, that alien forcibly trapped the Uni-Power within itself, using its own energy-absorption power, so the Uni-Power was not on board with what it was doing, and was grateful to the Surfer for taking the alien down.